# Sentry logging with multiple extra parameters

Tags: sentry

I have a question regarding how to include extra information in a sentry log. I have the below method to write an error log with error message and stack trace. Is there a way to add additional parameters (eg: Data), rather just being able to select one? Thanks

```
public void LogError(Exception exception)
{
   _ravenClient.CaptureMessage(exception.Message, ErrorLevel.Fatal, extra:exception.StackTrace);
 }
```